# How to avoid multiple "OR"s in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

| patient_id | procedure_1 | procedure_2 | procedure 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | . | . |
| 2 | A | B | . |
| 3 | . | . | . |
| 4 | . | . | . |
| 5 | C | . | B |
| 6 | D | . | . |
| 7 | A | . | . |
| 8 | B | A | . |
| 9 | C | . | . |
| 10 | D | A | . |

And the prompt is to select those patients who had either procedure A or B (it doesn't matter the order or whether they had both procedures).

So far i've got this:

```
library(dplyr)
procedure_list <- list("A","B")
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
      mutate(procedure_test = case_when(procedure_1 %in% procedure_list| 
                                 procedure_2 %in% procedure_list|
                                 procedure_3 %in% procedure_list ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0) %>%
      subset(procedure_test==1)
```

and it's working.
The problem is that i will be working with around 50 variables recording procedures (procedure_1, procedure_2 , ... , procedure_50), 10 procedures ("A", "B", ... "J"), and approximately 7 million observations, which is why I would like to optimize this code as best as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe %>%
  mutate(proc_test = if_any(starts_with("proc"), ~ . %in% c("A","B")))
```

---

Tested on 7M rows x 50 cols (3GB data), it takes 18 seconds on my machine. Is that fast enough for your use case?

```
set.seed(42)
col = 50
row = 7E6
# this part of generating 350M units of fake data is slow, takes 1-2 min
dataframe <-  matrix(sample(c(letters, LETTERS, rep(".", 10)), row * col, replace = TRUE), ncol = col)
dataframe <- dataframe %>% as.data.frame()
dataframe <- dataframe %>% setNames(paste0("proc_", 1:col))

# 18 seconds
dataframe %>%
  mutate(proc_test = if_any(starts_with("proc"), ~ . %in% c("A","B")), .before = 1)
```

Comment: To get 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE, multiply by 1: `if_any(starts_with("proc"), ~ 1 * (. %in% c("A","B")))`

Comment: You are awesome! Super fast enough, thank you very much!